# can annotation get context object?

Tags: java, annotations, spring-aop

Maybe title "can annotation get context object?" is not correct, but I don't know how to give it a right and clear one.

I use Spring AOP + Java Annotation to save log, here is my code:

CategoryAction.java :

```
@ServiceTracker(methodDesp="save category, category name:"+this.category.getName())
public String save() throws Exception
{
    this.categoryService.save(this.category);
    this.setJsonDataSimply(null);
    return "save";
}
```

TrackAdvice.java :

```
public Object trackAround(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable
{
    String log = "success";
    ServiceTracker tracker = null;
    Method method = null;
    AbstractAction action = null;
    try
    {
        Object result = point.proceed();
        action = (AbstractAction) point.getTarget();
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) point.getSignature();
        method = signature.getMethod();
        tracker = method.getAnnotation(ServiceTracker.class);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log = e.getMessage();
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (tracker != null)
        {
            String userId = (String) ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get(Constant.USERID);
            if (userId == null)
            {
                userId = "unknown";
            }
            TrackLog t = new TrackLog();
            t.setWhen(new Date());
            t.setUserId(userId);
            t.setResult(log);
            t.setMethodName(action.getClass().getCanonicalName() + "." + method.getName());
            t.setMethodDesp(tracker.methodDesp());
            this.trackService.save(t);
        }
    }
}
```

`ServiceTracker` is my own annotation, in my `TrackAdvice` class, I get the current executing method, if the method has a `ServiceTracker` annotation, then save the `methodDesp` in annotation to database.

Now the question is the `methodDesp` in annotation is dynamic, I want to get `this` object and retrieve its `category` property.

It seems that Java Annotation doesn't support this, maybe it supports but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use some sort of expression language in the annotation value and then run some interpreter in your advice code. One example using SPEL could look like this:

```
@ServiceTracker(methodDesp="save category, category name: #{category.name}")
```

And in your advice code, you can then extract the expression token, make use of a `SpelExpression` and pass it the `target` reference as root object (you may want to check what's available out of the box in the SPEL API for supporting your use-case(s)).

Comment: thanks very much. The expression is like this:`methodDesp="'save category, category name:'.concat(category.name)"`, I just tested.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that Java Annotation doesn't support this

You are correct - there is no way to do this in pure java.

The reason is that because annotations are **static metadata** that is wired into **classes** and defined at **compile-time** (`this` start to exist only at run-time, not compile-time).

In other words there is no straightforward way to make `methodDesp` of some annotated method of some class dynamic, since it's value has to be resolved statically, at compile-time.

However, technically there is a way to do something like you want. What I talk about is using [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) to either manipulate or create your classes (and annotations applied to them) at runtime. But be warned that this is rather hacky way and I generally would not recommend to go there.